# Windows server share read-only from network and write locally

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

Question:

How do I Deny Change without Denying Read on Windows File Share Permissions?

Details:

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server.  I would like to create a file share that is read-only to a group when accessed from the network (via the file share) but writable when the members of the group are connected via Remote Desktop.

I thought I would be able to accomplish this by making the folder writable from file permissions but deny write using the share permissions.

I am unable to set 'Deny Change' without also being forced to 'Deny Read' in the share permissions dialog. (I don't want to deny read...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local perms consist of only NTFS perms. Effective share perms are the union of the NTFS perms + the share perms. Just make the share perms read only.

[image: ntfs perms]
[image: share perms]

Comment: I want other groups to have write access to the file share.  By not having Full Control and/or Change allowed will this prevent other groups from writing to the share?

Comment: Then use share perms of Group1=Read, Group2=Write